Can we find the determinant with some other way, perhaps using some properties$?$

If $A$ is a $2×2$ matrix and it is given that $\operatorname{tr}(A)=3$ and $\operatorname{tr}(A^3)=-18$, find $\det(A)$.

I can solve this problem by assuming $A=\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{matrix}\right)$
We have $a+d=3$, also when we cube it's and do some manipulations we will get the value of $ad-bc$ as $5$.

Is there any other way of doing this, without doing the cube perhaps using some properties$?$ Because cubing this matrix is somewhat a lengthy process.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Evaluating cubic must be included, but not for matrix.
Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ be an eigenvalue of $A$, then
$$\begin{align}
&\text{tr}(A) = \lambda_1+\lambda_2=3 \\ 
&\text{tr}(A^3) = \lambda_1^3 + \lambda_2^3 = -18 \\ 
&\det A = \lambda_1 \times \lambda_2
\end{align}$$
holds. Now well known identity
$$(x+y)^3 = x^3 + y^3 - 3xy(x+y)$$
gives the result directly.

It is independent of your $a, b$ (or $c, d$) but let me rename to avoid confusion.

Why is tr(A^3) a^3+b^3?? If the eigenvalue of A are a and b does this mean that eigenvalue of A^3 will be a^3 and b^3?

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Since $Ax = \lambda x$ implies $A^3 x = A^2(Ax) = A^2(\lambda x) = A(\lambda^2 x) = \lambda^3 x$, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^3$ is an eigenvalue of $A^3$. (Similarly you can generalize this to $A^n$.)

Thanks i got it
